# Views: is it better to set instance variables or pass in locals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have question about passing variable from controller to views.
What is best practice, performance, and finally what is advantages and disadvantages to pass variable in locals or pass variable as instance variable ? Example:

```
controller.rb
@string = "Some string"
```

And then in view:

```
view.erb
<%= @string %>
```

or better to pass

```
controller.rb
render some_path,
      :locals => {
          :string => 'aww',
      }
```

and then inside view:

```
<%= string %>
```

How it will be with objects , booleans ? is there make any diferrence in performance? What is better practice?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails, it's best practice to pass the instance variables to your views. Rails developers are used to it, it's familiar, it's less typing, it works.

Yet, my personal preference is to pass `locals` to `render` because it makes your view variables more explicit. It also has a benefit of raising a "no method" exception if you mistype a variable rather than getting a "nil" exception when using instance vars.

I'm not sure there is going to be much difference in performance either way. Might be interesting running some benchmarks. But if you're using Rails, then view rendering speed is probably not your top concern.

Note that if you use an instance var in your controller to memoize a method's result (say to cache an expensive calculation), than that instance var "leaks" into your view. You probably didn't need it in your view, but you still get it (because Rails exposes any instance vars in controllers to your views). Thus, passing local vars is more explicit in communicating "my view relies on this variable")

Comment: Perfect! This is response I've expected. Thank You sir.